# .htaccess 301 redirect not working?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a static page of the form page1.html in my root directory and another page index.php also in the root directory. What I am trying to do is move all old incoming links to point to a wordpress directory. I got the main domain to redirect via the .htaccess and the index.php which I found from my hosting providers help site (i.e. abc.com now redirects to my wordpress installation folder properly).

The problem I have now is, any pages that were directly linked to or indexed are still showing up. For example abc.com/page1.html is still visible. I tried using the following .htaccess code to redirect to the new site:

```
redirect 301 /page1.html abc.com/index.php
```

The above code should be correct from my understanding as my index.php loads up the wordpress data (same method used for the correctly working abc.com redirect), but for some reason the redirect is not taking place.

Here is the general layout of my .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress redirect
# This part is for the abc.com -> wordpress folder redirect.
# Code taken strait from my hosting provider's help tutorial.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /WordpressInstallation/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /WordpressInstallation/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Problem code below
# Static page redirects
redirect 301 /page1.html /index.php
redirect 301 /page2.html /index.php
.
.
.
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or how I can achieve the result I am looking for?

Edit:

It may not be necessary information, but the page1.html, page2.html, etc files are located in the root directory with the .htaccess file while the wordpress installation is in a folder named wordpressInstallation in the root directory. I just thought I would clarify that if the question didn't make that clear.

```
/
---wordpressInstallation
------Wordpress files (head.php, index.php, style.css etc.)
---page1.html
---page2.html
.
.
.
---index.php
---.htaccess
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't mix `mod_rewrite` rules and `mod_alias` rules.
2. Keep redirect rules before default WP rule.

Use this `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` (**one level above wordpress directory**):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(page1|page2)\.html?$ /wordpressInstallation/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

And remove `Redirect` directives from your Wordpress .htaccess.

Comment: Just tried it with appropriate sections changed and it still did not handle the abc.com/page1.html redirect.

Comment: Is this .htaccess inside `/WordpressInstallation/` path and you're trying to redirect root path `/page1.html` ?

Comment: Just edited the question to clarify the structure of the files.

Comment: My root directory .htaccess file has just the two lines you mention in your updated answer. My wordpress .htaccess file is empty. The redirect seems to be taking place, but now it seems like i am getting an infinite redirect ending in a 404 error

Comment: Where does `index.php` reside? Is it in root or in wordpress directory?

Comment: There are two index.php files. The first is located in the root directory and requires 'wordpressInstallation/wp-blog-header.php' while the second index.php file is in the wordpressInstallation folder and requires 'wp-blog-header.php'. The goal is to have everything redirect to the wordpress directory and load the wordpress site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77355/discussion-between-anubhava-and-mrjman006).