# htaccess Redirects with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working with a GoDaddy Hosted Wordpress website.

I have users that will attempt to go to `<mywebsite.com>/jobs` and I need them to be redirected to `<mywebsite.com>/newpath/corporate-opportunities/`.

I am under the impression that I can place rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` file that exists at the root of my GoDaddy Hosted installation.  I have the following in place:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   http://<www.mywebsite.com>/jobs    http://<www.mywebsite.com>/newpath/corporate-opportunities/ [R]
</IfModule>
```

The first set of rules (within the Wordpress Begin and End comments) is what is commonly put in place for the Wordpress 'permalink' URL rewrites so they are pretty.  The rewrite rule after the Wordpress block is how I am attempting to do the redirection.

I am not able to get it to work.

Comment: Possibly more suited as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132467/htaccess-301-redirect-not-working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your redirect rules *above* the WordPress rewriting ruleset, so that they are seen before-hand. Additionally, the `RewriteRule` pattern (the first part) is always the request URI, and not the fully-qualified URL - as you are working with one domain, you also do not need to use the fully-qualified URL in the substitution part. Lastly, you need the `L` flag to stop processing at that point.

```bash
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^jobs/?$ /newpath/corporate-opportunities/ [R,L]
</IfModule> 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Mike... Thank you so much!  Works like a charm.  Awesome!